# Problem with beamer and listings package, cannot obtain pdf

Tags: beamer, errors, listings

I want to use `\usepackage{listings}` in a beamer presentation. I obtain "Process exited normally" but it says "Error no file found". The process exits normally but texmaker doesn't find any pdf file. Do you know where is the problem?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
hello world
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

when I put an `%` before `\usepackage{listings}` all is good and I obtain my pdf...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. Your code compiles normally here on texmaker 4.2.

Comment: It compiles also on my computer but I cannot see any pdf file. In the repertory there is a pdf file produced but it is impossible for me to open it, it says it is damaged...

Comment: Which OS do you use? Have you tried deleting the PDF, closing and reopening texmaker, and recompiling?

Comment: I use windows 8. Yes I've already tried this but it doesn't work...

Comment: That is strange, I failed to reproduce the problem with your MWE.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @fonfox: Do you use a rather recent TeX distribution?